# How to Re-write Function as Unit Step Function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Write the function given by: $cos(t)$, $t ∈ [0, 2π)$ and $0$ otherwise, in terms of unit step functions.

This step is at the beginning of solving a Laplace Transform, which I can do, I just don't understand this initial step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that

$$f(t)=\cos(t)(u(t)-u(t-2\pi))=\begin{cases}\cos(t)&,t\in [0,2\pi)\\\\0&,\text{elsewhere}\end{cases}$$

where $u$ is defined by

$$u(t)=\begin{cases}1&,t\ge 0\\\\0&,\text{elsewhere}\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

@Dr. MV An alternative solution, with the same definition of $u$ (or as u).

$$f(t)=\cos(t)u(t)u(2\pi-t)=\begin{cases}\cos(t),&t\in [0,2\pi)\\\\0,&\text{elsewhere}\end{cases}$$